# How to update badge count in iOS?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, badge

I am using `TabbedPage` in Xamarin forms. In iOS I am not able to update `TabbedPage` badge item value. I am using custom renderer for iOS. My code is :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(BottomTabbedPage))]
namespace Graysons.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class BottomTabbedPage : TabbedRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
            TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(208, 208, 208);
            TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            TabBar.Items[1].BadgeValue = "1";
            TabBar.Items[2].BadgeValue = "1";
        }
    }
}
```

When app is initialized first time badge value is display. But problem is I want to update badge value when my app is open from background mode(i.e. press Home button and reopen app). Also when in foreground mode I want to update this value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The code you've shown will always have a value of "1". Is this the code you're using, or are you doing something else? (This will help me understand the issue you may be having.)

Comment: Actually I am using Settings Plugin for Xamarin and stored value of notification count in that and bind that value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have the BadgeValue added as a property to your TabbedPage.
You should then be able to pull it out with:

```
if(Element is MyTabbedPage myTabbedPage)
        {
            TabBar.Items[1].BadgeValue = myTabbedPage.YourProperty;
        }
```

Comment: How can I add property into TabbedPage?